# Exe file build by Qt 5.10 could not run

Tags: c++, qt

I use Qt 5.10 in windows 7.

The compiler is VC 2010 32Bits.
Debuger is cdb.exe (X86).

I could not run the exe built and error shows： The procedure entry Point DisableThreadLibraryCalls could not be located in the dynamic library.
api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-1-1.dll

When I tried to debug my program in Qt creator, it finished just after the debug begins and did not stop at any my break point.

Comment: maybe this helps [Deploy an Application on Windows](https://wiki.qt.io/Deploy_an_Application_on_Windows). A Qt exe needs to find it's dependencies to run.

Comment: or this [Qt for Windows - Deployment](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html)

Comment: Did you really compile Qt 5.10 with Visual Studio 2010? I believe this can not be done and  you can't use Qt binaries  compiled with  a different compiler.

Comment: @drescherjm  I used Qt creator 5.10. The complier is VC 2010 32 Bits

Comment: This combination should not work.

Comment: @drescherjm why？

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 is too old for this version. You need at least 2013 but preferably 2015 or greater.

Comment: [https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.10/supported-platforms.html](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.10/supported-platforms.html)

Comment: You also need to use Qt binaries for the Visual Studio compiler you are using (with the exception of 2015 to 2019 which are binary compatible with each other - in this case you can use binaries compiled with either of the 3 versions).

Comment: @drescherjm The project was originally compiled with VC2010 by others. We all use Qt creator

Comment: You must have used an older version of Qt with that. Or used the wrong Qt binaries and ignored the Undefined Behavior.

Comment: This may help you to get an older version of Qt that is compatible with Visual Studio 2010: [http://www.saoe.net/blog/building-qt-5-6-2-on-windows-7-with-visual-studio-2010/](http://www.saoe.net/blog/building-qt-5-6-2-on-windows-7-with-visual-studio-2010/)

Comment: I have changed the environment as you said, now it says: The procedure entry Point DisableThreadLibraryCalls could not be located in the dynamic library. api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-1-1.dll